# Auto add content to specific entity queue dependant on chosen taxonomy term

Tags: views, entities, 9

I have a *People* content type, which has an *Expertise* field which is a taxonomy term reference field.

There will then be an EntityQueue set up for each *Expertise* term.

What I'd like to do is automatically add all People profiles to the end of their relevant *Expertise* EntityQueue. For example, *Management* EntityQueue will auto populate with all people who are managers, and you will be able to reorder them by editing the EntityQueue, so the most senior managers appear first.

Looks like there was a module in Drupal 7 which added entities to queues by taxonomy term, but I've not found a way to easily do this in Drupal 9.

There is a Drupal 9 *Auto Entityqueue* module, but this only allows items of a specific content type to be added to an EntityQueue.

I could also add all people to one EntityQueue and then use separate views which filter by the relevant *Expertise*. This would end up being one massive People queue though, and it makes it tricky as some people might belong to more than one *Expertise* and their place in the full list of People would be "global," and you couldn't reorder them in each individual queue.

I have a feeling that setting up some rules which trigger on save is the way to go, but it's not something I've ever touched, and I'm hoping there is another, less technical, way of achieving this.

Comment: Sounds like this should be done programmatically then. Either by hooking into the people node entity save or by using the Queue API?!